# How to get rid of $ signs from the column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset has quite a few columns containing $values with comma e.g. $150,000.50. Once I import the datasets:

```
datasets = pd.read_csv('salaries-by-college-type.csv')
```

The imputer object is failing since bunch of values in those columns as $ values. How do I correct it in the python program

Here's my dataset. Except for School Type rest all has $ values with comma. Is there a generic way to remove those $ and commas from those column values

```
School Type                          269 non-null object
Starting Median Salary               269 non-null float64
Mid-Career Median Salary             269 non-null float64
Mid-Career 10th Percentile Salary    231 non-null float64
Mid-Career 25th Percentile Salary    269 non-null float64
Mid-Career 75th Percentile Salary    269 non-null float64
Mid-Career 90th Percentile Salary    231 non-null float64
```

Here's a sample of my dataset:

```
School Type Starting Median Salary  Mid-Career Median Salary    Mid-Career 10th Percentile Salary   Mid-Career 25th Percentile Salary   Mid-Career 75th Percentile Salary   Mid-Career 90th Percentile Salary
Engineering $72,200.00  $126,000.00     $76,800.00  $99,200.00  $168,000.00     $220,000.00 
Engineering $75,500.00  $123,000.00     N/A $104,000.00     $161,000.00     N/A
Engineering $71,800.00  $122,000.00     N/A $96,000.00  $180,000.00     N/A
Engineering $62,400.00  $114,000.00     $66,800.00  $94,300.00  $143,000.00     $190,000.00 
Engineering $62,200.00  $114,000.00     N/A $80,200.00  $142,000.00     N/A
Engineering $61,000.00  $114,000.00     $80,000.00  $91,200.00  $137,000.00     $180,000.00
```

Comment: `df.column = df.column.str.strip('$')`

Comment: Thanks... what about the commas in the 150,000.50?

Comment: `...strip(",")`

Comment: @Fallenreaper that isn't how strip works.  It only removes the characters at the beginning and end

Comment: That isn't your dataset.  Those are the dtypes.  I need to see the data with the dollar signs and what not.

Comment: i added the dataset in the question. let me know your suggestion please

Comment: @piRSquared oh, crap.  Ok.  language mistake.  I think of `trim` for ends, and `strip` for string-wide.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a csv that looks like this.
*Note:* I don't really know what your csv looks like.  Make sure to adjust the `read_csv` parameters accordingly.  Most specifically, the `sep` parameter.

```
h1|h2
a|$1,000.99
b|$500,000.00
```

Use the `converters` argument in `pd.read_csv`
Pass a dictionary with the name of the columns you want converted as the keys and the function that does the converting as the values.

```
pd.read_csv(
    'salaries-by-college-type.csv', sep='|',
    converters=dict(h2=lambda x: float(x.strip('$').replace(',', '')))
)

  h1         h2
0  a    1000.99
1  b  500000.00
```

---

Or suppose you imported the dataframe already

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    'salaries-by-college-type.csv', sep='|'
)
```

Then use `pd.Series.str.replace`

```
df.h2 = df.h2.str.replace('[^\d\.]', '').astype(float)

df

  h1         h2
0  a    1000.99
1  b  500000.00
```

---

Or `pd.DataFrame.replace`

```
df.replace(dict(h2='[^\d\.]'), '', regex=True).astype(dict(h2=float))

  h1         h2
0  a    1000.99
1  b  500000.00
```

Comment: Here's my dataset, except for the 1st column rest all has $ and comma values, how do I get those corrected generically.

Comment: School Type                          269 non-null object
Starting Median Salary               269 non-null float64
Mid-Career Median Salary             269 non-null float64
Mid-Career 10th Percentile Salary    231 non-null float64
Mid-Career 25th Percentile Salary    269 non-null float64
Mid-Career 75th Percentile Salary    269 non-null float64
Mid-Career 90th Percentile Salary    231 non-null float64

Comment: @Kda you need to edit your question and past that data there.

Comment: If this is the dataset from kaggle, the problem could be something else. Its a csv and loads pretty easily in pandas otherwise. Just requires df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('$|,', '')) after creating the df