# Pandas groupby.sum() not working properly?

Tags: python

I gamble on a site called PredictIt.  I've downloaded a csv file with all of my Profit and Loss for all markets that I've ever gambled in.  I called it dat.

The csv has data for Profit and Loss on every trade ('ProfitLoss'), and the name of the market in which I traded ('MarketName').  After converting the financial data to floats (the $ had to be removed and the () had to be removed for negative numbers), I try to use groupby to get profit and loss for each market, rather than for each trade.  But the market_groups file does not include a column for profit/loss.  It's adding other numerical columns, but not the one I modified.

```
for index, row in dat.iterrows():
    if dat['ProfitLoss'][index][0] == '(':
        length = len(dat['ProfitLoss'][index])
        dat['ProfitLoss'][index] = float(dat['ProfitLoss'][index][2:length-1]) * -1
    else:
        length = len(dat['ProfitLoss'][index])
        dat['ProfitLoss'][index] = float(dat['ProfitLoss'][index][1:length-1])
    print(type(dat['ProfitLoss'][index]))

market_groups = dat.groupby(['MarketName']).sum()
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596599/how-to-get-rid-of-signs-from-the-column-values-in-python

Comment: Changing the financial data to floats worked just fine.  I checked that.  The issue was specifically the groupby.sum() function not working.

Comment: can. you please share some sample data please. I know it may be your personal data. Please scrub and share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `dtype` of the Series for "ProfitLoss" is inferred from the original data, i.e. string.  You need to either set the Series to float, or set `numeric_only=False` in `sum()`.

That is, either changing the `dtype` of "ProfitLoss"

```
dat = dat.astype({'ProfitLoss': 'float'})
market_groups = dat.groupby(['MarketName']).sum()
```

Or setting numeric_only to `False`

```
market_groups = dat.groupby(['MarketName']).sum(numeric_only= False)
```

should work.

Also wanted to point out that the `-1` in `dat['ProfitLoss'][index] = float(dat['ProfitLoss'][index][1:length-1])` should probably not be there? I think you meant this to remove the ending bracket `)` but you don't need to do that in the else clause.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  Would I be correct in saying that the column has a type in addition to the actual cells?

Comment: Yes, you can check the dtypes of your columns with `dat.dtypes`.  Previously, the dtype of column "ProfitLoss" was probably `object` which can contain different numeric and non-numeric "cell" value types, if you will.